# OSX and Xcode compatbility

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I built a large portion of an app on a 2007 Macbook (15 inch). I recently bought a cheap macbook off of ebay (2007) Macbook 2.1. I saved my apps workspace to a flash drive and am now tinkering with it to get it back up to speed so I can work with it. The only problem is I didn't realize that the Model I bought is not compatible with Yosemite or the latest version of X code (it's running snow leaopard i beleive: 10.6.8).

So basically I downloaded Xcode 4 (the only version of Xcode still compatible) and it seems very dated that it seems ridiculous. I now get 22 compiler warnings. I read somewhere that you have to have xcode 5 or later just to submit apps. When I tried downloading xcode 7 it said my system needs OSX 10.10 or later.

Are my compiler warnings solely compatibility issues and should I just take my flash drive saved project to a new macbook or what? Because I tested it fine just a month ago locally.

**Additional info:** My current Macbook 2.1 is running OSX 10.6.8 and X Code 4.0.2
but the app was built on a macbook running the latest version of OSX and X code

**Update.** Now the compiler is giving me 16 warnings...it seems very erratic. Can someone please explain?

**My question:**

1. can someone explain or validate my compatibility suspicions?
2. is running X Code on an OSX 10.10 virtual box an option?
3. should I just get a new mac?

Comment: Choice #3 (not necessarily new, but certainly newer)

Comment: Sounds good, Im putting this mac on craigslist as we speak. In the meantime please humor me: whats your take on running a virtual box with yosemite?

Comment: No, you cannot virtualise a 64bit os on 32 bit host hardware.

Comment: the key bit is your mac has a 32bit cpu...

Comment: i agree with choice 3 also haha

Comment: unfortunate, best of luck my friend

Comment: you should get a new mac.

Comment: If not new, then newer :) I have a 2009 MB Pro and (IIRC) it can run all the latest offerings.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. the winner... Macbook pro 2007 15 inch (same as my old model lol) it too can run yosemite and the latest versions of Xcode.